# PowerBI - Count Blank Values of specific Columns

Tags: count, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

My table looks a little like this. The last column is what I'm trying to figure out how to calculate. I can easily do this in Excel - but not sure how to write my formula in PowerBI

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more clever way to do this, but a simple DAX expression can do the job.

```
CountBlanksInRow = 
VAR data1blank = IF (ISBLANK(Sheet1[Data 1]), 1, 0)
VAR data2blank = IF (ISBLANK(Sheet1[Data 2]), 1, 0)
VAR data3blank = IF (ISBLANK(Sheet1[Data 3]), 1, 0)
RETURN data1blank + data2blank + data3blank
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can count it without specifying the individual columns. if that is what you are looking for. I would do it something like this:

```
Data Missing =
    COUNTBLANK([Project Title]) 
    + COUNTBLANK([Status]) 
    + COUNTBLANK([Object])
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather then using DAX or Measure, The best option is you can create the custom column in Power Query and the code will be as below-

```
Number.From([Project Title] = null)
    + Number.From([Status] = null)
    + Number.From([Objective] = null)
```

Here below is the sample code window-

[image]